# Eclipse Java Debugger make if statement condition be true

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, if-statement

I want to make a if statement become true only when I am debugging.

Example:

```
if(giveMyNumber() == 3){ 
     System.out.println("Is number 3");   
}

public int giveMyNumber(){
  return 1;
}
```

So i want to stop de debugger in if statement and simulate as **(giveMyNumber() == 3)** is **true** in order to go inside the if and print "Is number 3"

Comment: not sure you can simulate `giveMyNumber() == 3` but if you assign it to variable and use variable as condition then you can make it true.
`boolean b=giveMyNumber() == 3; if(b){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Eclipse feature called [**Force Return**](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/ref-forcereturn.htm) to return the value `3`:

> Forcing an early return from a non-void method requires an expression to be evaluated. For example, if a method was going to return false you could return a value of true by selecting an expression in the **Display View** and invoking **Force Return**. In the following example, `elementCount` is not equal to zero, and would return false (see debug hover showing the value of `elementCount`).
>
> [image: Force Return Example]
>   <sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/images/force-return-code.png))</sub>
>
> From the **Display View**, we could enter the value we want returned, select it and use the **Force Return** command to force the method `isEmpty()` to return with that value (in the following example we will force `isEmpty()` to return with the value `true`).
>
> [image: Force Return Action in the Display View]
>   <sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/images/force-return-action.png))</sub>

Comment: Yes i know this method, but i want to know if it is a faster way to do it.

Comment: @Mikel No, this is the only way, and it is not really that slow. Press F5 to enter the method `giveMyNumber()`, type the number `3` in the Display pane, right-click and select Force Return, then press F6 to enter the `if` statement. Simple enough, once you know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Breakpoint. Add a breakpoint and select Breakpoint Properties...

Take a look in image bellow.

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

Select you breakpoint and write the condition, in your case:

```
giveMyNumber() == 3
```

Comment: This will make the execution break *when* the condition is true, but OP is asking how to override the logic of the `if` statement when stepping through the code, in order to enter the `if` block, even though the condition is actually `false`.

Comment: @Andreas. I miss your point. "So i want to stop de debugger in if statement and simulate as (giveMyNumber() == 3) is true in order to go inside the if and print "Is number 3"". I didn't get where Mikel is askint to override...

Comment: I want just jump inside the condition temporaly in debug mode as:  if(true){System.out.println("Is number 3")}

Comment: @Mikel, is the answers enough for you question?

Comment: @josivan OP wants a normal breakpoint on the `if` statement. When there, OP wants to enter the `if` statement, even though it normally wouldn't because method returns `1` which is not equal to `3`. OP wants to *override* the behavior of the code at debug-time, in order to exercise the `if` block.

Comment: @Andreas. Off topic: what you mean OP? Anyway, if the question is like you described, your answer is good enough.

Comment: @josivan OP is short for referring to the person asking the original question. Don't know what it actually stands for.

Comment: "OP" means ["Original Poster"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op)